# Total harmonic distortion and DFT

Tags: fourier, harmonics, total-harmonic-distortion

I am trying to understand a design that would enable us to measure/determine the total harmonic distortion.

Key points:

- The system is microcontroller (TI, C2000, dual-CPU) driven electronic
- It has a decent and functional external ADC circuitry (ADC resolution is 12-bit)
- The input (whose THD is to be calculated) to the ADC system is a 3-phase supply, 230V (RMS)
- The fundamental frequency is 50 Hz
- Number of samples to be taken: 400 samples per cycle/waveform.
- Maximum number of harmonics to be calculated for 50

I read through a lot of material for understanding the math for 'nth' harmonics in a signal. For example, 2nd harmonic would have the frequency twice the fundamental frequency. I figured that the complex waveform at 2nd harmonic would be summation of the two signals and can be represented as:

[image]

Where, *'series 1'* is fundamental sine wave, *'series 2'* is the sine wave with frequency twice the fundamental and *'series 3'* is the complex resulting waveform.

I looked into the DFT-related references and I understand how to calculate DFT of signal. Based on samples I figured that I need to generate a 400-point DFT matrix (400x400) for DFT calculation (multiplication).

I have a few questions:

- Since I want to calculate up to fiftieth harmonic, I assume my equation *f(t)* would be a large equation consisting sum of all signals that (can) have frequencies for up to 50th harmonics. Am I right?
- Since the number of samples is 400, I need to generate a 400-point DFT matrix (possibly using MATLAB,) is that correct?
- The output of the DFT is 400 values, obtained from the DFT (after matrix multiplication) and typically referred as magnitudes. How can those be used (in a C program) to calculate THD?
- I don't understand the relation between the DFT and THD.

Comment: THD is the RMS result of each discrete value in the DFT. But you are wrong to assume you need 50 harmonics. You only need 5 but with a resolution of 10 bits

Comment: if you really want the 50th Harmonic, you need to sample at least 100X the fundamental.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: Hi, the external ADC has a resolution of 12 bits.

Comment: The more resolution you want, the higher your sampling rate needs to be to capture the peaks in THD.

Comment: For higher frequencies, you must sample faster.  Sampling rates are usually given as "samples per second."  You seem to be saying that you will be taking 400 samples for each 50Hz cycle.  That would be a sampling rate of 20000 samples per second, which would be well over Tony's suggested minimum of 100 times the fundamental (50Hz fundamental * 100= 5000 samples per second.)  Please check and see if that's what you meant.

Comment: @JRE: I am certain that we are taking 400 samples for each 50Hz cycle. Thats well over whats required by Nyquist criterion.

Comment: So now you have the basics of a solution.  Sample at 20 KSa/sec; perform your 400 pt DFT; then pick off and sum up the DFT bins you're interested in.  I'm not familiar with the C2000 microcontroller.  Does it have built-in FFT or filter functions, or are you going to have to code your own?

Comment: @SteveSh: I am going to have yo code it. I have checked, C2000 doesn't have a built-in FFT.